# How to set the font which Agda code uses?

Tags: fonts

I am following the documentation found here:
https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0.1/tools/generating-latex.html

From this, I have came up with the following example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{agda}

\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

ℕ

\begin{code}

data ℕ : Set where
  zero : ℕ
  succ : ℕ → ℕ

\end{code}

\end{document}
```

However, when I compile using

```
agda --latex example.lagda
xelatex example.tex
```

The first ℕ character appears in the PDF fine, however the ℕ inside the code environment does not. When I look at the xelatex logs, I see

```
Missing character: There is no ℕ in font [lmsans10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
```

Which would imply to me it's not looking for the ℕ character inside either the main font nor the math font. Is there a way to specify the font for the code environment to use?

The generated latex from the `agda --latex example.lagda` command can be found at https://pastebin.com/6gBw51Jb.

Comment: I don't have the agda.sty and won't try to find it, but it looks as if it is using a sans serif font, so you could try `\setsansfont{XITS}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Seems correct! ℕ is now showing inside the Agda code block. If you could post your comment as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the agda.sty and won't try to find it, but it looks as if it is using a sans serif font, so you could try `\setsansfont{XITS}`.

Comment: You, sir, have just saved me after half a night spent in frustration being unable to get my special character to display correctly in my masters thesis... Thank you very much!

Comment: @Isti115 I'm not a sir, I'm a women.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry!!! In this case, you, ma'am, have tremendously helped me, I'm truly grateful!